# Group a list and sort that list by occurrence in java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have a large list of names (first name and lastname): For example:

`{ john a, david x, marry u, john b, david y, john c}`

The result should be (grouped by first name, ordered by frequency of the first name, not considering last name.):

```
john b
john a
john c
david x
david y
marry u
```

I have a quite large list (30M instances), so I must consider the complexity of the algorithm.

Comment: What approaches have you tried?

Comment: Why is `john b` before `john a`? Also where did `david x` and `david y` go?

Comment: grouped by first name and sorted by occurrence- shouldnt john a come first

Comment: @SlaterTyranus I mean I do not care the last name.

Comment: @HoaVu Have you looked at `SortedSet` and either creating a `Comparator`, or implementing `Comparable` for your class?

Comment: Is the order correct now?

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: It's all ok.

Comment: @VivinPaliath yes, I have implemented Comparable and sort them then create a dictionary to count. But I think it's bad

Comment: @VivinPaliath: It's a class implemented Comparable and has 2 String attributes.

Comment: Oh, wait! Do you mean that you want them sorted by frequency of first name?

Comment: just create a "table on memory" in a database, and have grouped/sorted query

Comment: @VivinPaliath I'm sorry if my question is ambiguous. I mean frequency of first name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Map<String, Integer> freq = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (String s: names):
    first_name = Arrays.asList(s.split()).get(0).toLowerCase()
    int count = freq.containsKey(name) ? freq.get(name) : 0;
    freq.put(name, count + 1);

Arrays.sort(names, new Comparator<String>() {
  public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    int c = freq.get(Arrays.asList(s1.split()).get(0).toLowerCase()) - Arrays.asList(s2.split()).get(0).toLowerCase();
    return c;
  }
});
```

Basically make a histogram of the frequency of first name occurrences, then just use it as a custom comparator.

It's just two operations so you're limited by the complexity of the most complex area of the problem and since the histogram generation is linear you're limited by the sort function which I believe is `nlogn` which is the best you can do with sorting.

Comment: I assumed that as well, but notice that the Johns appear before the Davids, and so natural ordering would not work in this case.

Comment: @VivinPaliath I think I just actually figured out what on earth the OP was asking, updating answer shortly.